# О прабабушках и прадедушках

Tags: словообразование

Читал, что в русском языке нет ограничения на количество приставок в этих словах. Но есть ли способы сократить их? Скажем, вместо "бабушка" с восемью приставками "пра" написать что-то вроде "бабушка в восьмом поколении"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, возможно. Представляте, если написать, например, бабушка в восьмом поколении, то нам придется использовать восемь приставок ***пра***, и так можно продолжать до бесконечности.

Comment: Т.е. именно "бабушка в восьмом поколении"? А это сколько приставок "пра"? 7 или 8? По идее, бабушка в первом поколении это просто бабушка, бабушка во втором уже прабабушка? Т.е. Количество поколений это цифра, на одну превышающая количество приставок, верно?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Не стоит, да и немыслимо, передавать эти отношения приставками. Лучше всего использовать предложенный вами вариант или воспользоваться иной описательной конструкцией, передающей такое отношение.